# Checking installed Yeoman generators

Tags: command-line-interface, npm, yeoman

What powershell command do I run to see what Yeoman generators I have installed? I'm assuming it's a npm command, but I have no idea since I'm new to CLI.

[image: the yo command]

This is what I'm seeing when I enter "yo" into the command line. I'm on version 1.0.0-rc.1.3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you should be able to use `yo -h` in 1.0.0-rc.1.3 and it will list your installed generators along with their generator tasks they provide.

Answer (score 23):

**Updated January 2016**

*Whilst the accepted answer is correct, it also prints alot of other noise to the screen.* It also leaves you still within the yo command-line upon completion.

The official **yeoman** command just to see list of installed generators is

```
$ yo --generators
```

This exits the yo CLI upon completion. This is really helpful if you wish to pipe the output to another program etc.

[image: yo generator]

Of course, if your intention is to actually run a particular generator, and you only have a few installed, then just running:

```
$ yo
```

is the way to go.

[image: yo generator two]

You can find a complete listing of all [published generators here](https://github.com/yeoman?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=generator-)

Comment: You can also find the version of the generator in question using npm -v on the command line. e.g.: $ npm -v generator-react-fullstack

Answer (score 13):

Just running `yo` should list your installed generators, and allow you to run them.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but I'm only given three options:
1.Install a generator
2. Find some help
3. Get me out of here!

Comment: I've updated the question with what I'm seeing in the command line. I thought i was in an older version of Yeoman but I'm running v1.0. I have looked everywhere and I can't find anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup node path:

```
export NODE_PATH=$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/
```

In my case node is in HOME directory.

Running `yo` after this will list all generators.